# CDF of entity of paired random variables?

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

If $2n$ samples are generated in the following way:

1. Draw $U_i\sim Unif[0,1]$ i.i.d. for $i=1,...,n$
2. Define $\tilde U_i := 1 - U_i$ for $i=1,...,n$

If I would now draw a random sample $X$ among these $2n$ samples, why wouldn't its distribution be a mixture of $Unif$ and $1-Unif$ and thus just $X \sim Unif$?

I'm not sure if it is clear what I am trying to ask, so let me give an analogy: Everyday a tree of random height $U_i$ is grown together with a second tree of height $1-U_i$. Now what is the CDF of the height of trees?

Comment: It is unclear whether your resampling is with or without replacement, but while individual elements of it would have a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, different elements would not be independent of each other.

Comment: Your question seems to imply that you think the distribution wouldn't be the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Why do you think that? (It is.)